# C++ to Java code translation

Tags: java, c++

I have following code in C++:

```
struct Foo { };

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Foo& f) {
   return os << "Foo";
}
Foo foo;
std::cout << print("Ha! %1%, x=%2% %1% %3%") % "Hej" % 1 % foo;
```

Because I don't think I understand that C++ code. What is appears, is that it is some kind of printf like function.
What I need, is to make it Java way. Any ideas, how to mark it work as it is, but in Java?

Comment: What do you mean "work as it is, but in Java?" For starters, Java doesn't even have structs.

Comment: System.out.println("Foo");  really?

Comment: That is certainly not C++ (you can't modulo strings!)

Comment: Well, looks like there is a custom print() function returning object with overloaded % used for pretty formatting. There is a lot of backup behind these 5-7 lines of code, to be honest.

Comment: Maybe this one can help you:
http://download.cnet.com/C-To-Java-Converter/3000-2213_4-10080009.html

Comment: @crashmstr: see boost::format, which does exactly that: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/format/doc/format.html

Comment: @Evan: Another reason why I prefer code with fully specified namespaces (or at least show all of the includes!)

Comment: @crashmstr: yea, he probably did: `typedef boost::format print;` or something similar.

Comment: I get very usefull informations from You. Especially from Evan Teran. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java has `String.format()` See this [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29).

This allows you to use printf-style format strings. For example:

```
System.out.println( String.format("Foo: %f\n", 3.14159) );
```

Comment: Or `System.out.format()` to cut out the middleman if desired.